# Service Oriented Architecture and Loose Coupling vs SQL JOINS

Tags: web-services, data-mining, soa

Let's suppose we have got a SOA infrastructure like the one painted below and
that every service can run on a different host (this is especially valid for the two extra-net service "web site" and "payment system").

[image: SOA infrastructure]

Clearly we have got a data (persistence) layer. Suppose it's implement through EJB + JPA or something alike.

If we want to join data (in user UI) between the different services I see at least a couple of alternatives:

- we want to do efficient JOINs at RDBMS level so we have a package (ie. persistence.package) that contains *all* the entities and session facades (CRUD implementation) which in some way has to be shared (how ?) *or* deployed for every service. That said, if I change something in the order schema I must redeploy this packages introducing tight coupling between pretty much everything. Moreover the database must be unique and shared.
- to avoid such issues, we keep an entity package for each different service (i.e. order.package) and let the services communicate through some protocol (soap, rest, esb, etc.). so we can keep data locally in each host (share nothing architecture) and we don't need to redeploy the entity package. But this approach is terrible for data-mining as a query that must search and return correlated data between multiple services will be **very** inefficient (as we cannot do SQL joins)

Is there a better / standard approach to the issues pointed above ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main motivation for SOA is independent components that can change separately. A secondary motivation,as Marco mentioned, is simplifying a system into smaller problems that are easier to solve.
The upside of different services is flexibility the downside is more management and overhead - that overhead should be justified by what you get back - see for example a SOA anti-pattern I published called [Nanoservices](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/Nanoservices.pdf) which talks about this balance

Another thing to keep in mind is that a web-service API does not automatically mean that that's a service boundary. Several APIs that belong to a larger service can still connect to the same database underneath. so for example, if in your system payments and orders belong together you shouldn't separate them just because they are different APIs (In many systems these are indeed different concerns but, again, that's not automatic)

When and if you do find the separation into services logical than you should follow Marco's advice and ensure that the services are isolated and don't share databases. Having services isolated this way serves toward their ability to change. You can then integrate them in the UI with a [composite front end](http://arnon.me/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Composite-Frontend.pdf). You should note that this works well for the operational side of the application as there you only need a few items from each service. For reporting you'd want something like [aggregated reporting](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/aggregated-reporting/) i.e. export immutable copies of data into a central database optimized for reporting (e.g denormalized star-schema etc.)

Comment: "this [only] works well for the operational side of the application as there you only need a few items from each service". indeed that's the problem: normally we need a lot of data from different services, complex lookups and real-time search in the UI. About aggregated reporting I see very few cases when this data could be considered immutable (so, commonly, denormalization introduces synching issues).

Comment: Well said Armon. I think the best for @gpilotino is to read a bit about DDD; this is a very good book: http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly, and move from there.

Comment: No @gpilotino denormalization does not introduce sync problems, don´t know where you got that from. Using different write and read model can indeed introduce sync problems but that has nothing to do with the data being denormalized.

Comment: You maybe your book as well :)

Comment: when I am talking about the need for aggregated reporting I really am talking about reports where you really want to integrate data that is across services with a lot of joins. I have implemented SOA successfully in may system including near-real-time ones. Also regarding immutability - any data can be made immutable with the addition of versions   .( @Marco :) )

Comment: "any data can be made immutable with the addition of versions", true. but if you refer to some OLAP system (i guess it from star-schema), the fact (imho) is we can only get, at best, a photography of the past. to make it as simple as possible, OLAP cannot answer trivial queries like "how many orders belong to users who *actually* are living in California" (trivial in OLTP) if not recording every change to every possible data that can be queried (suppose: everything). anyway, the directions you pointed out look good, but my overall feeling is that soa real-time aggregation is an open problem.

Answer (score 3):

Oh my friend you're just complicating the whole scenario, but it is not your fault, companies like MSFT, Oracle and other big vendors of enterprise class software like to make a big picture of something that is way easier, and they do it for a reason: scaling services vertically means more licenses.

You can take a different approach and forget for a moment about all those big words, EJB, JPA... and like someone smart once said, split the big problem in smaller parts so that rather than having a big problem you have a couple of small problems which in theory should be easier to deal with.

So you have a couple of services in your system: people, payment system, orders, products, ERP... for a moment lets think that those boundaries are right in terms of business entities. Imagine those services are different physical departments of you company, which means that they only care with the data that belongs to them, nothing else.

You could then say that Payments department has its own database, the same applies to Orders, of course they still need to communicate with each other as all departments do, and that can be made easy with a system generated public surrogate key. What this all means is that each service maintains the referential integrity of all its internal entities using internal keys, but if records need to my made available to other services you can for example use a Guid key, e.g.:

[image]

The payments service needs the order ID and the Customer ID, but those entities belong to their own services, so instead of sharing a private key (primary key) of each record, each record will have instead a primary key and a surrogate external key the services will use to share among them. The thing is, you should aim to build loose coupled services, each with its own "small" database. Each service should also have each own API, which should be used not only by the front end, but by the other services as well. Another thing you should avoid is using DTC or other transaction management provider as a service wide transaction guarantor, it is something that can be archive easily with just a different architecture approach.

Anyway, read, if you haven't already about DDD, it will give you a different overview on how to build enterprise class software, and btw EJB, run away from them.

**UPDATE:**

You could use something like event SOA, but lets keep things simple here. A registered client comes to your site to place an order. The service responsible for this is the Orders. A list of external IDs for the products is submitted to the Orders service which then register the order, at this point the order is in a "awaiting payment" status and this service returns a public Guid order ID. For the order to be completed the customer needs to pay for the goods. The payment details are submitted to the payment's service which tries to process a payment, but for that it needs the order details because the only thing the frontend sent was the order id, and to do that it uses the GetOrderDetails(Guid orderId) from the order´s API. Once the payment is completed the Payments service calls yet another method of the Order´s API PaymentWasCompletedForOrder(Guid orderID). Let me know if there is anything you are not getting.

Comment: ok but this still does not solve the "big joins with correlate data" problems. for sure, i can keep the external keys in the orders subsystem, but when i need a list of orders correlated w/buyer's name that will be inefficient (oders of magnitude respect a sql join) to ask the people subsystem and so on. forget about ejb and technologies, my issue is, if i don't want to sync/propagate schema changes (to keep things loosely coupled) what's the most efficient way to cope with this.

Comment: you might say, just keep the extra data for each kind of report (data list) you need in each system. let's say, in the web subsystem duplicate the whole list of orders so web site users can look at them. but this introduces the problem: how to keep things in sync ? suppose i change the order status in the order subsystem this must be mirrored into the web site. so, in this scenario of denormalized data, keep things in sync would become an integration hell.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the problem is that web system is not a proper department so it should not exists. Like I said each service should have its own API layers. In the orders domain you have the list of orders associated with the buyer's external id which is then mapped to the private ID in the people service, so I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: i get it. anyway, the issue is efficent search and report of real time data (like in the "list of my orders" example i wrote above) from scattered systems. i'm ok with GetThisById(uuid), the fact is that often we need aggregation and complex lookups. ie. meaningful searchable list of orders in the web system *and* list of orders in the order system. the web system *is* a proper department. consider the common scenario where the client has an internal ERP + CRM system (intranet) and wants to push products from the ERP to one ore more external web sites + keep web-users in sync with the CRM.

Comment: But I did not say it all, you have the concept of read model, which should be what feeds your front end. Rather the normalize databases for each service the read models are unnormalized databases. Read here:http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Comment: first of all thank you for you time. secondly, that model mapping trick looks cool at least to "hide" some coupling. but, imho, it does not really differ from some kind of evoluted "mediator" pattern that  exploit the underline techology (oo + data mapping) in a smart way, still assuming the db is unique and shared, as well as the code.

Comment: But thats the difference, the db should not be shared, the services should be autonomous, which means that if one service is down the others can still perform some work waiting in a queue. DDD, SOA... it is a bit complicate to explain here. IMHO the best you can do, is have an open mind and explore other ways of achieving what you need. You´re already doing it, so it should be fairly simple for you to pick up on those "new" concepts.